# How to recreate a view by xml?

Tags: list, view, content-database, xml

I can retrieve the xml data of a view which is stored in the  `[WSS_Content].[dbo].[AllWebParts]` table.

example of decompressed content of a view:

```
<root>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="DocIcon" />
    <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" />
    <FieldRef Name="Modified" />
    <FieldRef Name="Editor" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Query />
  <RowLimit Paged="FALSE">30</RowLimit>
</root>
```

Is there any way to create a view using this xml ?
Usually I create a view by following code:

```
var list = Site.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
var view = new ViewCreationInformation();
view.Title = "NewVIEW";
list.Views.Add(view);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to update via direct xml then use SetViewXml method of view. So your code would like this

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Test"];
SPViewCollection collViews = list.Views;
string strViewName = "NewVIEW";
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection collViewFields = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
string strQuery = "";

collViews.Add(strViewName, collViewFields, strQuery, 100, true, false,
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Grid, false);

SPView view = list.Views[strViewName];
view.SetViewXml("<View>" + //xml truncated for clarity
    "<Query/>" + 
    "<ViewFields>" + 
        "<FieldRef Name=\"DocIcon\"/>" + 
        "<FieldRef Name=\"LinkFilename\"/>" + 
        "<FieldRef Name=\"Modified\"/>" + 
        "<FieldRef Name=\"Editor\"/>" + 
    "</ViewFields>" + 
    "<RowLimit Paged=\"FALSE\">30</RowLimit>" +
"</View>"); 
view.Update();
```

However, the best way is to update individual properties (Query, ViewFields and RowLimit) of the view.

Comment: I can't find property SchemaXml in ViewCreationInformation class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewcreationinformation_members.aspx

Comment: you are right @isxaker. I have update the code with the correct API SetViewXml. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: is it client model(dll) of microsoft sharepoint ?

Comment: This is a server object model. I am not sure if view creation using direct xml is possible in CSOM. If you really need CSOM then first map the xml to object by creating classes with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes. Use ViewCreationInformation and fill up ViewFields, RowLimit members with your DataMember properties.